# Send command shortcut to NSTextView's next responder

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit, foundation

I have an MacOS app that listens to key events by implementing `NSWindow.keyDown(with event:)`. I use this to enable shortcuts like `⌘ n` to create a new item. This works well except when there is an `NSTextView` that is the first responder. In that case, the text view will swallow the event and my `keyDown` function will not get called. How do I prevent this and have the textview send events to the next responder (eventually my `NSWindow`)?

Comment: Have you tried `performKeyEquivalent(with:)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subclass `NSTextView` override `keyDown` method and call next responder:

```
import Cocoa

class TextView: NSTextView {
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
    }

    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        super.keyDown(with: event)
        nextResponder?.keyDown(with: event)
    }
}
```

Comment: this totally works! but it's kinda hacky no? every textview in my app needs to be this subclass?

Comment: I don't know why would you consider this a hack. If you would like to propagate the event yes